# how to get rid of casting warning

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
#define NUMOFDMABUF 20
u8 *data[NUMOFDMABUF];

int main()
{
    for (u32 i = 0; i < NUMOFDMABUF; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (void *)(RX_BUFFER_BASE + (i * MAX_PKT_LEN)); //-Wint-to-pointer-cast
    }
}
```

This is for bare metal application and i want to explicitly set memory addresses of ram locations to an array of pointers.  The code works, but how do i write the code to avoid the occurrence of this warning?

If i explicitly set the address as a value, no issues... but when i do it this way it throws the the warning.  I am brain farting, so thoughts appreciated :)

Comment: We need to know what compiler you're using... kinda important detail that....

Comment: We also need to see some code. Afaik, u8, u32, or RX_BUFFER_BASE are not standard, and your warning may come from the definition of those (on my computer, depending on typedef u32, I get, or I don't get the same warning)

Comment: @Fraser Addison The casting does not make a sense. It is entirely unclear what you are trying to achieve with the casting. And why are you casting an integer to a pointer?

Comment: The compiler is ARM v8 gcc (aarch64-none-elf-gcc).  I'm trying to set an array of memory pointers to explicit RAM offsets by iteration.  The code works... no errors...  just this warning...

Comment: What is the type of `RX_BUFFER_BASE` (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/5vrxaxnq6)?

Comment: #define RX_BUFFER_BASE 0x40000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`how do i write the code to avoid the occurrence of this warning?`

This may-or-may-not work in all environments.
It is just a proposal that *may* work for this OP.

I haven't done "bare metal" stuff to any serious degree.
But this compiles on my old computer without warnings...

```
int main() {
    uint8_t *d[20];
    memset( d, 0, sizeof d ); // start clean

    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof d/sizeof d[0]; i++ )
        d[i] +=  0x2468 + ( i * 256 ); // NB "+="

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not going to go anywhere near dereferencing any of those pointers though.

Comment: hmmm weird... no warnings with this method.... thx

Comment: @FraserAddison If you've found any of the answers offered to have solved your problem, please "tick" to accept that answer showing this question is resolved...

Comment: whoops! silly newbie! thx again

Comment: @FraserAddison We don't do this just for the thrills `:-)`... You'll soon be mentoring, too, with all of the same joys and sorrows... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The text of the warning produced by gcc is more descriptive.

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

The OP mentions in the comments how `RX_BUFFER_BASE` is defined:

```
#define RX_BUFFER_BASE 0x40000000
```

That macro is later textually expanded in the line

```
data[i] = (void *)(RX_BUFFER_BASE + (i * MAX_PKT_LEN));
```

The type of `i` is a non standard `U32`, I'll assume it to be a 32-bit unsigned integer. `MAX_PKT_LEN` is undisclosed, but I'll assume it to be defined as `RX_BUFFER_BASE`.

Now, the type of an integer constant is the first type in which the value can fit<sup>1</sup>, so `0x40000000` could be an `unsigned int` or an `unsigned long int` depending on the implementation, or if we consider fixed width types, an `uint32_t`, but not an `uint64_t`.

Using an integer suffix, like `0x40000000ull`, would have forced it to be an `unsigned long long`.

We can assume<sup>2</sup> that the other variables in that expression have the same type, while pointers, in OP's implementation, have a wider representation. Therefore the warning.

The asker could have used a type specifically designed for this kind of pointer arithmetic, like `uintptr_t`, which is an unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer to `void`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
const uintptr_t buffer_base = 0x40000000;
```

---

<sup>1) C17 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2018): 6.4.4.1 Integer constants (p: 45-46)  or see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant#The_type_of_the_integer_constant</sup>

<sup>2) Sorry, that's a lot assumptions, I know, but it's not entirely my fault.</sup>